Prove that Fourier transform is $L^p$
I am working on a problem, and I need to show that, if $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by
$$f(x) = \frac{|x|^a}{(1+|x|^2)^{(a+b)/2}}$$
and $2a>-n$, and $b > n$, then the Fourier Transform $\hat{f}$ of $f$ is in $L^p$ for every $2 \leq p \leq \infty$.
Knowing that the Fourier transform 'changes regularity to integrability', I'd assume that this result essentially boils down to $f$ being sufficiently differentiable, but I don't see a clean way to differetiate this function many times.
For $p=2$, one can also apply Perseval's identity to get the result, as long as $f \in L^2$, which is easy to prove.
My questions are: Do I just need to find the formula for the derivative of this function, and show that it is differentiable sufficiently many times, or is there another way?

Hausdorff Young inequality should prove useful here

As the inequality is not part of the course Im taking, I think I am looking for something else.

If you can show $f(x)$ is in $L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$, then $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is in $L^{\infty}({\mathbb R}^n)$, and if you can show $f(x)$ is in $L^2({\mathbb R}^n)$, then $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is in $L^{2}({\mathbb R}^n)$. So if you can show that $f(x)$ is both $L^1({\mathbb R}^n)$ and $L^2({\mathbb R}^n)$, then $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is in both $L^{2}({\mathbb R}^n)$ and $L^{\infty}({\mathbb R}^n)$. This will automatically ensure $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is in $L^p({\mathbb R}^n)$ for all $2 < p < \infty$ since the intersection of $L^{2}({\mathbb R}^n)$ and $L^{\infty}({\mathbb R}^n)$ is contained in all such $L^p$ spaces.
The Hausdorff-Young inequality is a stronger version of the above which you can prove using interpolation.

I didn't, I was asleep:) I agree with you on not giving complete solutions, and thanks for this.

Great answer. One interesting feature of this question is related to the common slogan "Fourier transform changes smoothness to integrability". In my opinion, that slogan is overrated and should be downplayed. Here, for example, it is quite misleading.
